# Use string startsWith on phrase

Tags: java, string, startswith

I created an autocomplete that should show users the results after they have been filters by `startsWith`.

For example, if users search for "harry potter", I had like it to return results that start with "harry potter" but I get all results that start with "harry", like the space in between the words breaks the phrase.

How can I use `startsWith` with a 2 words string?

I use:

```
for (String item : autoBookNames) {
    if (item.toLowerCase().startsWith( query.toLowerCase() )) {
        filteredTitles.add( item );
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `query.toLowerCase()` returns "harry potter" ? If you are sure, then maybe try [regular expression](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/package-summary) instead?

Answer (score 1):

I made a simple Main java class and seems like your code is working:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String query = "Harry Potter";

    List<String> filteredTitles = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> autoBookNames = new ArrayList<>();
    autoBookNames.add("Harry potter: Adfg");
    autoBookNames.add("Harry Potter: SDFSDF");
    autoBookNames.add("Not harry potter title");
    autoBookNames.add("Harry potter is awesome");
    autoBookNames.add("Narnia is better than Harry Potter");
    autoBookNames.add("Lord of Rings");

    for (String item : autoBookNames) {
        if (item.toLowerCase().startsWith( query.toLowerCase() )) {
            filteredTitles.add( item );
        }
    }

    filteredTitles.forEach(System.out::println);

}
```

Output:

1. Harry potter: Adfg
2. Harry Potter: SDFSDF
3. Harry potter is awesome

Maybe the main problem is in the comparation of the startWith in your item and in your query.

Comment: I needed to use filteredTitles.clear() as it stores to previous results.

Comment: I am glad you fixed it

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class JavaPractice {

    public static void main(String[] argh){
        String[] autoBookNames = {
            "Harry potter is ossm",
            "Harry potter is Great",
            "Harry",
            "Joe"
        };
        ArrayList<String> filteredTitles = new ArrayList<String>(5);
        for (String item : autoBookNames) {
            if (item.toLowerCase().startsWith( "harry potter" )) {
                filteredTitles.add( item );
            }
        }
        System.out.println(filteredTitles);
    }
}
```

I ran this code. It's working fine. The output is [Harry potter is ossm, Harry potter is Great]. Maybe there's some issue with `query.toLowerCase()`. See what it is returning. You will find the issue.